# sddm wrong touch coordinates on steam deck and garbled content on connecting second monitor

Tags: debian, steam, sddm

I'm trying to set up a Debian-soon-to-be-known-as-Bookworm (aka "testing", at the time of this writing) system on a steam deck, using KDE plasma as desktop environment and sddm as login manager. Works pretty well so far, but some glitches remain. For instance, I'm currently trying to convince sddm to play nicely in both built-in-touchscreen-only and dual-monitor setups.

Generally: The steam deck's touch screen seems to have a resolution of 800x1280, with its right edge facing up. I added

```
xrandr --output eDP --rotate right
```

to /usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup to have sddm displayed in the expected landscape orientation. So far, so good -- although xrandr states the touch screen's dimensions were 60 mm x 60 mm, which is absolutely not true.

The problem is, However, that the mouse pointer doesn't properly follow touch movements. When swiping horizontally, the pointer moves vertically, and vice versa -- like the two were working in two coordinate systems perpendicular to each other. Once a KDE plasma session is running, touch operation works fine, though -- mouse follows touch flawlessly.

Question #1: How to make sddm / X / xinput (or whoever else might be responsible) to convert touch coordinates to the correct pointer coordinates?

Second problem: When booting the the steam deck while docked with an external HD monitor connected, sddm displays fine on the external screen, but only the most-left two thirds of the built-in screen seem to properly show a part of sddm's UI; the rest of the area appears to be occupied by some other section of the theme's background.

Question #2: Well... what is going on here?! Any ideas how the presence of a second monitor could make sddm restrict itself to using only two thirds of the space available on the first monitor -- and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, problem #2 solved: In addition to adjusting the built-in screen's rotation, I also had to extend the total screen size using the `--fb` option.

Working command in `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup` is:

```
xrandr --fb 3200x1080 --output eDP --mode 800x1280 --rotate right --right-of DisplayPort-0
```

Edit 2023-02-23: Problem #2 solved as well!

Problem #1 (pointer coordinate system rotated relative to touch coordinates) remains.

Edit 2023-02-23: Problem #1 solved as well! With a little help from https://crocidb.com/post/investigating-touchscreen-issue-steam-deck/ and some linear algebra, I came up with the following lines of code in `/usr/share/sddm/scripts/Xsetup.sh`:

```
EXTERNAL_SCREEN_STATUS=$( xrandr | grep 'DisplayPort' | awk '{print $2}' )
TOUCHSCREEN_ID=$( xinput | grep 'FTS3528' | head -n 1 | awk '{print $5}' | sed 's/id=//g' | grep [0-9] )

if [ "$EXTERNAL_SCREEN_STATUS" == "connected" ]; then
    xrandr  --fb 3200x1080 \
            --output eDP --mode 800x1280 --rotate right \
            --output DisplayPort-0 --mode 1920x1080 --right-of eDP
    xinput set-prop $TOUCHSCREEN_ID 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0 0.4 0 -0.741 0 0.741 0 0 1
else
    xrandr --output eDP --mode 800x1280 --rotate right
    xinput set-prop $TOUCHSCREEN_ID 'Coordinate Transformation Matrix' 0 1 0 -1 0 1 0 0 1
fi
```

Depending on whether or not the external display is connected, different transformation matrices need to be applied to the touch coordinates. If there's no external monitor, it is enough to rotate the touch coordinates by 90°, but with two monitors attached, the also need to be scaled down so that they coincide with the built-in display only -- rather than the combined (virtual) display size. With resolutions r_builtIn = 1280x800 and r_external = 1920x1080, the x and y scaling factors are calculated as

s_x = r_builtin,x / (r_builtin,x + r_external,x) = 1280 / (1280 + 1920) = 0.4

s_y = r_builtin,y / (r_builtin,y + r_external,y) = 800 / (800 + 1080) = 0.741